# How to prevent FileLockNodeManager spamming Wildfly log?

Tags: logging, jboss, wildfly

after upgrading to Wildfly 22.0.1 I get thousands of entries like that in the logs:

```
2021-02-19 08:40:54,979|DEBUG|mis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager|Server still has the lock, double check status is live
2021-02-19 08:40:54,979|DEBUG|mis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager|getting state...
2021-02-19 08:40:54,979|DEBUG|mis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager|trying to lock position: 0
2021-02-19 08:40:54,979|DEBUG|mis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager|locked position: 0
2021-02-19 08:40:54,979|DEBUG|mis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager|state: 76
2021-02-19 08:40:54,979|DEBUG|mis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager|Status is set to live
```

I tried to set the log level for this class to ERROR

```
        <logger category="mis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
```

But I still get those messages every 2-3 seconds.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards
Mark.

complete Logging conf in standalone-full.xml:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="io.jaegertracing.Configuration">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="mis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch-jberet:2.0">
        <default-job-repository name="in-memory"/>
        <default-thread-pool name="batch"/>
        <job-repository name="in-memory">
            <in-memory/>
        </job-repository>
        <thread-pool name="batch">
            <max-threads count="10"/>
            <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
        </thread-pool>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: What does the rest of your logging configuration look like?

Comment: added logging configuration

Comment: Given the log format and the configuration posted it looks like you've got some kind of log configuration file in your deployment. Is there a log4j.xml or log4j.properties in your deployment?

Comment: yes there is, but these log entries and the system they're originating from are not part of our project, but of Wildfly

Comment: Those are definitely not from WildFly itself. The pattern doesn't match what the logging subsystem suggests so it must be coming from the logging configuration in the deployment.

Comment: what's strange is, up until Wildfly 22.0.1 these log messages were not there (same project, same logging config)... not sure what to make out of it all...

Comment: Have you looked in your deployment for a some kind of logging configuration file?

Comment: yes I have, I'm discussing this issue internally right now, still not sure...

Comment: looks like this is a side effect of an unfortunate log setting in our logging configuration. The mentioned packages/classes are not explicitly configured there, but with some shuffling around we got rid of the log entries.

Thanks for your help! :-)